# Create class dict of instances

Tags: python-3.x, class

I would like to let a class keep track of its instances in a dictionary. For example, for this class I would like to get

```
class Test(object):
    count = 0
    elements = {}
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        Test.count += 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return "[a=%s, b=%s]" % (self.a, self.b)

a = Test(1, 3)
b = Test(3, 5)
c = Test(9, 9)
Test.count
# Test.elements # WANT: {1:"a", 2:"b", 3:"c"}

# Added later:
# How to avoid appending to list
Test.el = []                
AA = Test(1, 3)
Test.el.append("AA") # avoid this?
BB = Test(3, 5)
Test.el.append("BB")
CC = Test(9, 9)
Test.el.append("CC")
print(Test.el)
# Then call the AA, BB, CC. Does not work either.
# for o in Test.el:
#     print(o.a)
```

How can I create an elements-dict like the class-count variable?

Thx+kind regards

Comment: What would be the key? Why not use a list?

Comment: Note that you will keep all the objects in memory, this can be bad behavior, since it is basically a memory drain.

Comment: A list would be ok too .. (and I don't want to copy the instances themselves, but only automatically create a dict or list which shows all the names).

Comment: @r.user.05apr what do you mean by *shows all the names* - what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: It's easier to think that any object doesn't know its name (and can have more than one) - what's `a = Test(1, 3); b = a; c = b;` supposed to show you for instance? Would not using a `dict` be better with the name as the key and then you're not keeping around references keeping the object alive...

Comment: I've added some lines above. The final goal is to have a dynamic list of "Test"-objects and then create a loop that does something (add to the variables or print them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do in the following way

```
class Test(object):
    elements = []
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        #Test.count += 1
        Test.elements.append(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "[a=%s, b=%s]" % (self.a, self.b)

a = Test(1, 3)
b = Test(3, 5)
c = Test(9, 9)
print Test.elements
```